# Uncompilable code-illegal start of expression

Tags: java

After checking multiple times and googling I sill can't sort out why I keep getting this error. Originally I had `double rosenbrock = (1-x)**2+100*(y-x**2)**2;` which I split into declaration and assignment, but this didn't solve it. I'm sure the problem should be quite trivial.

```
public double objFunction(double input1, double input2){
        double x = input1;
        double y = input2;
        double rosenbrock = 0;
        rosenbrock = (1-x)**2+100*(y-x**2)**2;
        return rosenbrock;

    }
```

EDIT: yes, the problem was in the line `rosenbrock = (1-x)**2+100*(y-x**2)**2;` I'm sorry I didn't explicitly mention this before. The error message didn't specify the source of the problem, hence I was confused about what could have caused it.

Comment: Which lines cause your error? What does `**` mean in Java?

Comment: Next time you may want to google what operators exist in java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java doesn't have `**` - that's Python. You can use [`Math.pow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29):

```
rosenbrock = Math.pow(1 - x, 2) + 100 * Math.pow(y - x*x, 2);
```

You can find a list of all valid operators in [Summary of Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Which lines cause your error?

What does `**` mean in Java? As far as I know, it is not defined.

The key to this and similar questions is to look at the line causing the error and the error message, as that will tell you what is wrong, or at least what you should look up in greater detail. This can prevent careless errors, which is really all this is.

Comment: The error message said nothing about the operator

Comment: @Alex: it certainly told you which line was causing the error. You neglected to post that in your question which suggests that you didn't put much importance to that piece of information. It is critical.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have `**` operator, if you want power, use `Math.pow()`

Answer (score 0):

don't use `**`.

use `Math.pow()` method, i.e.,

rosenbrock =  Math.pow(1 - x, 2), + 100 * Math.pow(y - Math.pow(x,2), 2);

Answer (score 0):

```
rosenbrock = (1-x)**2+100*(y-x**2)**2;
```

You know, if I had to take a shot in the dark, I'd say the Java compiler is having a full blown cardiac arrest at `**`. That won't compile I'm afraid. Replace them with `*` for multiplication.

For power, we use `Math.pow()`, and not `^` or `**`.